# Did Nash prove that every game or every symmetric game has a symmetric equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

Most references seem to state that Nash showed every symmetric game has a symmetric equilibrium point, but as far as I can tell from Nash's paper, he actually showed the much more general statement that every finite game has a symmetric equilibrium point.

I realise the references wouldn't be wrong, but why don't they state the more general result?

Comment: As far as I remember, Nash's paper only talks about equilibrium, there is no reference to any symmetry whatsoever. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: To be clear, I'm referring to his PhD thesis, a copy of which is located at https://www.princeton.edu/mudd/news/faq/topics/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf

Comment: It might also be worth reminding people that Nash's definition of a symmetric game is more general than most people use, it includes any fair games like matching pennies.

Comment: Hi Nick!  Asymmetric finite games need not have symmetric equilibria -- the players need not even have e.g. the same number of strategies.  Did you ask what you meant to ask?

Comment: @GHfromMO There are two papers. *Equilibrium Points in n-Person Games* from 1950 only contained a proof that an equilibrium exists. *Non-Cooperative Games* from 1951 (essentially the published thesis) contains a proof that every game has a symmetric equilibrium.

Comment: @Michael: Actually I read the 1951 paper, but only the proof of Theorem 1. I never read the part about symmetries, so I was certainly wrong in my first comment.

Comment: Hi Noah! I asked what I meant to ask, though yeah I did kind of assume all players have the same number of strategies. I just find the wording of the theorem very strange, I can see that Nash only defines symmetric n-tuples for actual symmetries of a game, but could one not define symmetric n-tuples for any valid permutation of the pure strategies (not necessarily a symmetry) then use Nash's argument to show the set of such symmetric n-tuples is a closed and convex subset and hence has a fixed point?

Comment: I'm guessing what's probably stupid about that is that there aren't many (any?) mixed profiles that are invariant under all permutations of the pure profiles? I get confused easily once I start talking about symmetries and mixed strategies.

Answer (score 12):

Nash defined symmetries of finite games and proved existence of an equilibrium point that is invariant under all symmetries. He called such an equilibrium a symmetric equilibrium. For this to make a difference, a game needs to have nontrivial symmetries. Generic games don't.

A clearer source for his result would be the [published version](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~ia/nash51.pdf) in the Annals of Mathematics. Theorem 2 there says: Any finite game has a symmetric equilibrium point.

Comment: > For this to make a difference, a game needs to have nontrivial symmetries. Generic games don't.

>Theorem 2 there says: Any finite game has a symmetric equilibrium point.

Comment: Don't those two statements contradict each other?

Comment: @NickHam No. A symmetric equilibrium is an equilibrium invariant under all symmetries of the game. In a generic game, the only such symmetry is the identity (there is a open dense, full measure set of games with no nontrivial symmetry). Nash did not define symmetric games.